# What is UpdateProcessor(solr) equivalent in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch. I want to do some processing of text content during indexing and store in different fields. I used to do this in Solr by using UpdateProcessors(Python,Java or Javascript).

I am new to elasticsearch.
I could see some posts saying elastic search doesnt support such operations during indexing. 
But, I do not want to do this outside indexing to avoid additional layers.

Can someone help me with some pointers or samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is none. Some of the things that Solr does with UpdateRequestProcessors (such as id generation, dynamic schema, etc) Elasticsearch has built in and - mostly - automatic.

But there is no way to specify a pipeline of components to apply to the incoming documents.

According to Shay Banon (Elasticsearch creator), such functionality belong to the client.